# What could be causing a Chinese font to not be displayed in safari and Mozilla but in chrome?

Tags: css, webpack, font-face, styled-components

I am looking for some guidance on how to debug if my font file is being fetched and if it is then what is causing it to not render on safari and firefox?

In safari I've got the following output
[image]

And in Chrome this is what it looks like
[image]

The code that sets up the @font-face is below

```
import {createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components';
import fontUrlTTF from './assets/SentyGoldenBell.ttf';
import fontUrlWOFF from './assets/SentyGoldenBell.woff';

export const GlobalStyles = createGlobalStyle`
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'SentyGoldenBell';
        src: url(${fontUrlTTF}) format("truetype");
        src: url(${fontUrlWOFF}) format("woff");
    }
```

A couple of things that I've looked into

1. Supposedly safari may not support ttf (I've now included a woff file)
2. The import statements correctly use a relative path over an absolute path
3. ttf's format() is "truetype" and not "ttf"
4. As I have the font installed as a local system font, it could be that chrome is using local() so I've removed that
5. I also considered if the font-face wasnt being applied due to it containing chinese characters without specifying a unicode range in the font-face declaration but in the safari image even the english characters dont have the font applied.
6. I believe webpack is correctly picking up the dependency as the /build directory contains a copied version of the font file.
7. Force refreshed the webpage in case there was anything cache related

I've also looked into the inspector and can see that the ttf file exists but its showing as within a bundle? Does the indicate that the font file has indeed been fetched?
[image]

Because its in a js bundle output by webpack is that why the inspector does not pick up that a font file was requested for over the network?
[image]

Comment: You mention Firefox. Have you checked the [font inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Edit_fonts)?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I did not realise there was that feature! Thank you. I have somehow managed to get it to work by restarting the server... I wonder if there is something going on with caching?